# Find functional sequence verifying certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

In a college assignment they ask to find a funtional sequence $ \{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$,  $f_n : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f_n$ is non-negative and continuous, verifying:
1) $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x) = 0 $ $\forall x \in [0,1]$, 2) $\nexists lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x)dx$.
Can anyone give me a hand please?

Comment: Note that $f_n$ can't be uniformly bounded (otherwise you'll have the convergence of the integral) so, you need each $f_n$ to be too big in a very small interval in order to fulfill that $\int_0^1 f_n\to\infty$ and $f_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f_n$ equal to 0 in $[0,1]$ except in the segment $[\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}]$ where it takes the value $n^2$ at $\frac{3}{2n}$ overlapping with the 0 part continously. See the picture bellow.

[image]

With this construction, $\int_0^1 f_n=\frac{1}{2n}n^2=\frac{n}{2}$ and $f_n\to 0$.

The key part here is that $f_n$ can't be uniformly bounded.

Comment: I think that your example converges pointwise in $(0,1]$  but not in $[0,1]$. Besides, what I meant was that the limit in the integral was neither a real number nor infinity.

Comment: in my example, $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$.